# How to convert xpath to java code

Tags: java, dom, xpath, sax

I have a xpath of an element and need to write a java code which gives me exactly the same element as an object. I believe i need to use SAX or DOM ? i m totally newbie..

xpath :

```
/*[local-name(.)='feed']/*[local-name(.)='entry']/*[local-name(.)='title']
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "gives me" the element? Do you want to extract it as XML to a string or a file, or do you want it as a Java object in some object model (there are many to choose from, W3C DOM, JDOM, DOM4J, XOM, etc., all of which support XPath to some degree).

Comment: Well, i just have a task which i supposed to write a java code that does the same thing as this xpath code..Yeah as a DOM4J object in java..

Answer (score 0):

Your comment suggests you want to use [DOM4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/), which supports XPath out of the box:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document doc = reader.read(new File(....)); // or URL, or wherever the XML comes from
Node selectedNode = doc.selectSingleNode("/*[local-name(.)='feed']/*[local-name(.)='entry']/*[local-name(.)='title']");
```

(or there's also `selectNodes` which returns a `List`, if there might be more than one node matching that XPath expression - quite likely if this is an Atom feed).

But rather than using the `local-name` hack like this, if you know the namespace URI of the elements in your XML you can declare a prefix for this namespace and select the nodes by their fully qualified name:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Map<String, String> namespaces = new HashMap<>();
namespaces.put("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
reader.getDocumentFactory().setXPathNamespaceURIs(namespaces);

Document doc = reader.read(new File(....)); // or URL, or wherever the XML comes from
List selectedNodes = doc.selectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:title");
```

Answer (score 0):

read here:
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/java-xpath-tutorial-example/

I found it while I were searching to find how to convert Xpath PMD-rule to java-rule,, I did not find what I need in it.
but, anyway may be you can find yours.

Comment: Please don't post external links as answers, as they may go out of data or disappear. It's better to summarise the answer in the body itself.